# Параллельное выполнение функций NodeJS

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, soap

Есть задача, необходимо отправлять запросы к SOAP сервисам, максимальное количество сервисов === 20.
Использую модуль async метод parallel.

```
function run(tasks, callback) {
    var goods = [],
        request = {};

    async.parallel(tasks, function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            for(var i in data){
                if (data[i].good instanceof Array)
                    data[i].good.forEach(function(good){
                        goods.push(good);
                    });
                else
                    goods.push(data);
            }

            if (goods.length > 0)
                request = {
                    Goods : {
                        Good: goods
                    }
                };
            else
                request = {
                    Goods : {
                        Good: {}
                    }
                };

            logger.info('OK');

            callback(request);
        }

    });
```

Если один из сервисов не доступен, прекращается выполнение и вызывается колбэк.
Вопрос, как можно это предотвратить?

Comment: это, наколько я помню, не форк и не тред, это просто то, как будут выполняться  асинхронные функции (не в очередь ставить (**.series()**), а выполнять как получится)

Comment: чтобы в тредах выполнять нужно юзать что-то типа https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads

Comment: WebWorker это не совсем то, он для распределения запросов от пользователя, у меня же запрос 1, но отправить его необходимо на 20 сервисов.

.series() это хорошо, но - 1. Он выполняется последовательно; 2. У него те же ограничения, если одна из задач завершится ошибкой, управление передается callback функции без ожидания завершения выполнения остальных задач.

Comment: @Guy вам нужна библиотека тредов, не async async не выполняет ничего параллельно, она упорядочивает асинхронное  выполнение. думаю webworker можно использовать для ваших задач,

Comment: вообще если бы вы тут код привели который к серверам коннектится, все было-бы проще и не надо треды юзать, у вас же в примере синхронный код, поэтому  и ждет.

Answer (score 3):

Просто не возвращайте ошибку через первый параметр callback, смотрите пример для понимания:

```
var async=require('async');

function test1(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() { //это асинхронный запрос типа
                callback(null,[new Date()]); //ответ
        },2000);
}
function test2(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                callback(null,[new Date()]);
        },1000);
}

function test3(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                callback("Oh error!",[new Date()]); //ошибка
        },100);
}

function resultShow(err,results) {
        console.log(new Date());
        if (err) {console.error("---====="+err+"=====---");}
        console.log(results);
        console.log('--------');
}

console.log(new Date());
console.log('--------');

async.parallel({one: test1,two: test2},resultShow); //вызываем через 2 секунды
async.series({one: test1,two: test2},resultShow); //вызываем через 3 секунды первым будет one
async.parallel({one: test1,two: test2,three: test3},resultShow); //выпадет через 100 миллисекунд
```